# Detecting Actual Browser Type on an iPhone / iPad

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When a Chrome user hits my site, on an iPhone or iPad, the browser type, as reported via JavaScript or Request.Browser using MVC, always reports Safari. I think this is because Chrome, or any other browser running on an Apple platform, must be built on top of Safari technology, as per Apple requirements. Is there any way to detect what the actual browser really is?

Comment: It's probably detecting WebKit. Safari and Chrome are both WebKit browsers.

Comment: What do you intend to do differently if it's Chrome? Chrome on iOS is using UIWebView so it *is* Safari for rendering purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed tell if it is Chrome on iOS by looking at the agent string for 'CriOS.' It will be there instead of 'Version.' See this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) for details.